# How to combine .where() queries in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Am trying to add this query to my search method.

```
books = Book.where("category_id LIKE?","%{params[:category]}%").where("price LIKE <= ?", "%#{params[:price]}%").
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :category

    def self.search(params)
        books = Book.where("title LIKE ?","%#{params[:search]}%") if params[:search].present?
        books = Book.where("category_id LIKE ?","%#{params[:category]}%").where("price LIKE <= ?", "%#{params[:price]}%")
    end
```

**books_controller.rb**

```
def search
    if params[:category].present?
      @books = Book.where(category_id: params[:category]) 
    elsif params[:search].blank?
      @books = Book.all
    else
      @books = Book.search(params)
    end
end
```

**search.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag search_books_path, method: :get do %>
<%= select_tag :category, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :name), :include_blank => "Select Category" %>
  <%=number_field_tag :price%>
<%=text_field_tag :search, nil, placeholder: "search" %>
 <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
```

Comment: What is the problem or error message you're getting? You should be able to chain `where` clauses together with no issues. I'm not sure about your usage of the `LIKE` syntax, however - are your `category_id` and `price` columns integers or text? `LIKE` is usually for text, but those sound like integer fields to me...

Comment: my [category_id] and price fields are both integers. i get no errors at all. the search don't just use the rule.  It uses only this rule      @books = Book.where(category_id: params[:category])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to chain them like this.

```
def self.search(params)
  books = Book.all
  books = books.where("title LIKE ?","%#{params[:search]}%") if params[:search].present?
  books = books.where("category_id LIKE ?","%#{params[:category]}%").where("price LIKE <= ?", "%#{params[:price]}%")
end
```

Don't know why you're using `LIKE` for integers though, I would think a simple `=` would do it. You also need `'` for your `LIKE` operator when comparing strings.

```
def self.search(params)
  books = Book.all
  books = books.where("title LIKE '?'",params[:search]) if params[:search].present?
  books = books.where(category_id: params[:category]).where("price <= ?", params[:price])
end
```

Comment: ThanK YOU ALL FOR YOUR SUPPORT. Definitely  i was not suppose to use LIKE for integer and my  search method omitted the "&&" argument.  Again what code do you use to highlight text

Comment: Highlight text?

Answer (score 1):

When you submit your search form, you are sending the `params[:category]` value and your first if statement `params[:category].present?` evaluates to true. That's why you are only getting the results of the:

```
@books = Book.where(category_id: params[:category])
```

You could have overwritten your if statement to this:

```
def search
    if params[:price].present? && params[:category].present?
      @books = Book.search(params)
    elsif params[:category].present?
      @books = Book.where(category_id: params[:category]) 
    else
      @books = Book.all
    end
end
```

Comment: Hi i just realized that i can no longer use the search field  input. what ever i type in it will return the full array of the books. i expected it to search for what  i typed inside it

Comment: when i add another if statement to specify the param search like if param[:search].present, ihave this error       'PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""
LINE 1: ...e LIKE 'B') AND "books"."category_id" = $1 AND (price <= '')
                                                                    ^
: SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE (title LIKE 'B') AND "books"."category_id" = $1 AND (price <= '')',